# Shortcut Keystroke

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2008

In Sql editor of SSMS, How to setup a short keys 
1) when I type 'sfw' and get "select * from  where" or
2) when I type  "sfw mytable" and get "select * from  mytable where".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need SSMBoost add-in for SSMS (I am developer of that add-in)

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS go to `Tools`
then  `Options` -> `Select Keyboard` ->
Give the shortkeys and give descriptions.